# Opening newer Oracle Application Testing (OATS) scripts in older version

Tags: java, testing, functional-testing, oracle-apps

Earlier I was using Oracle Application Testing Suite (OATS) version 12.2 & upgraded to version 12.4 to check the functionality & recent changes.
I forgot to take a backup of my scripts. After opening the new version, it migrated all scripts to the latest version. Since i have to share these scripts with other people who still have 12.2, how can i get these newly migrated scripts to open in the older version?

I installed the older version again to try & get them to the older version, but I cannot open them either.
Any suggestions on how I can get them to open in older OATS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the scripts to a notepad from the 12.4 OATS version. Re-installed the 12.2 version & created the scripts again.

Apparently, once the scripts have been migrated to a higher version, it is not possible to migrate them back to the lower version. So a back up would be necessary or you en up with double the work

Answer (score 0):

Yes once you migrate to new version , Tool will generate .jwg file in scirpt folder which is executable file for Open Script.

or Workaround is navigate to Script path and copy Script.Java file and replace in older version.
You may want to write some shell script if you have lot of scripts.

for more Tips on Oracle Application Testing Suite, you may find here
http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips/